# complex equation, minus/plus error

Tags: complex-analysis

I've solved this equation $$z^2+(2-2i)z-6i-3=0$$ and I almost got the correct answer. That is, if I multiply the answers with -1 it's correct. And I can't find what I'm missing...

$(z+1-i)^2+2i-6i-3 = 0$

$(z+1-i)^2 - 4i -3 = 0$

$(z+1-i) = a + bi$

$a^2-b^2 = 3, 2ab = 4, a^2+b^2 = 5$

$ a = -2, b = -1$
or
$a = 2, b = 1$

which gives the answears

$-1-2i$ and $3$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off you have $$z+1-i=a+bi$$ so that $$z=(a-1)+(b+1)i$$

With $a=-2, b=-1$ this gives $z=-3$, and with $a=2, b=1$ you should get $z=1+2i$.

I suspect it is just that you did things in a hurry?